# Проблема при подключении библиотеки Attribute "minTextSize" has already been defined

Tags: java, android, android-library

Хочу подключить библеотеку compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+' в проэкте для телфона и для часов. Соответственно я в gradle (phone) я подключаю эту бибилеотек и в gradle (wear) так же подключаю,  и получаю ошибку

```
Error:(148) Attribute "minTextSize" has already been defined
```

Т.е. один и тот же атрибут дублируется. Как можно избежать этого дублирования?

wear.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

phone.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

    //facebook sdk
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'


    //MY DEPENDENCIES:

    //Profress bar's
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'

    //Auto resize text in TextView
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'

}
```

project.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Проект компилируется? покажите часть кода класса, где вы определяете `minTextSize`

Comment: @miha_dev я его нигде не определяю, нет не компилируется, потому что при подключении либы  - выдает ошибку и проект не собирается!

Comment: попробуйте в градл файле wear убрать. вы данную библиотеку используете в xml файле разметки?

Comment: @miha_dev в смысле убрать? я ее наоборот добавить туда хочу. Да я хочу ее в в xml использовать!

Comment: @miha_dev мне одна и та же библиотека нужно в модуле phone и в модуле wear

Comment: библиотека `me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+` конфликтует с какой-то другой библиотекой. Ради эксперимента уберите ее в модуле wear. А лучше добавьте код gradle файлов к описанию проблемы

Comment: @miha_dev Я убрал библиотеку из модуля phone и подключил к wear все равно выдало ошибку. Можно ли как то подключить библиотеку разом на телефон и часы а не по-отдельности?

Comment: в градле ничего криминального нет, так что давайте посмотрим на xml файл разметки. может вы два раза используете `xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` ?

Comment: @miha_dev так я в разметке этот элемент не использую, библиотека же не подключается!

Comment: По всей видимости, библиотека `me.grantland:autofittextview` не адаптирована под разработку для wear модулей. я так понимаю, если ее оставить в app файле, в в wear модуле удалить, то компилится все ок?

Comment: @miha_dev да, с этим все ок!

Comment: @miha_dev знаете какие то способы динамически менять размер шрифта?

Comment: я б написал свой класс наследник `TextView`, в нем переопределил метод `onMeasure`. оттуда взял бы ширину контейнера. вытащил бы текст `getText()` и измерил бы его длину с `Paint mTextPaint = new Paint(); ... mTextPaint.measureText(mText);` и уже если ширина меньше длинны текста последовательно уменьшал размер шрифта `mTextPaint.setTextSize(float newValue)`